# Online MCTS and MCPD training

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am looking to get my MCTS then a MCPD.  I learn better by watching lectures and working on labs.  What are the best online resources for this?

Comment: Specifying the long for of your abbreviations wouldn't hurt. I know MCTS as monte carlo tree search, but I doubt that's what you're interested in.

Comment: MCTS: Microsoft Certified Technology Specialist
MCPD: Microsoft Certified Professional Developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- http://www.cbtnuggets.com/certification
- http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/olt/courses.aspx
- http://www.appdev.com/info.asp?page=mscert&s=home

direct link for MCTS  cert

http://www.cbtnuggets.com/certification?cert=109

Comment: I looked at each of these but it doesn't look like theres any complete MCTS courses for Visual Studio 2010.  cbtnuggets has a few that look good, I'll definitely check that out.

Comment: search in that page for Microsoft 70-515: .NET 4 MCTS (Web Apps ) and Microsoft 70-515: .NET 4 MCTS (Win apps) if you are interested in visual studio 2010